# How to use survey to analyze the American Housing Survey data using replicate weights

Tags: r, survey

I'm analyzing data from the American Housing Survey, which ship with replicate weights to compute correct standard errors, in R with `survey`, but I want to make sure that I'm specifying the design correctly.

Here is how I do it:

```
svy <- svrepdesign(data = ahs,
                   weight = ~WEIGHT,
                   repweights = "REPWEIGHT[0-9]+",
                   type = "Fay",
                   rho = 0.5,
                   scale = 4/160,
                   rscales = rep(1, 160),
                   mse = TRUE)
```

I set `rho` to `0.5` because, in in section 3.1 of the guide to use replicate weights published by the Census Bureau where they explain how to compute standard errors with SAS (https://www.census.gov/content/dam/Census/programs-surveys/ahs/tech-documentation/2015/Quick%20Guide%20to%20Estimating%20Variance%20Using%20Replicate%20Weights%202009%20to%20Current.pdf), they say to use the option VARMETHOD=BRR(FAY) without specifying any other options and, according to the SAS documentation (http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/142/surveymeans.pdf), the default value for this parameter is 0.5.

I set `mse` to `TRUE` because, in the formula they give for the standard error in section 4, the sum of squared deviations is calculated around the estimate of the statistic computed with the full sample weights.

Finally, I set `scale`to `4/160` and `rscales`to `rep(1, 160)` because, in that same formula, the sum of squared deviations is multiplied by `4/160` but there is no multiplier inside the sum operator.

However, when I look at Anthony Joseph Damico's webpage on the American Housing Survey (http://asdfree.com/american-housing-survey-ahs.html), he does that:

```
ahs_design <- 
    svrepdesign(
        weights = ~ wgt90geo ,
        repweights = "repwgt[1-9]" ,
        type = "Fay" ,
        rho = ( 1 - 1 / sqrt( 4 ) ) ,
        mse = TRUE ,
        data = ahs_df
    )
```

Forget about the names of the weight variables, which just changed in 2015 (presumably after he wrote that webpage), he's doing the same as me except that he doesn't specify the `scale` and `rscales`. Based on what I explain above and the documentation of `survey`, it seems to me that he should specify them as I did, but I've never used replicate weights with `survey` before, so I would like to make sure.

P. S. What I find even weirder is that, when I try not to specify `scale` and `rscales`, the standard errors I compute seem to be the same as when I do. This means that it probably doesn't matter in practice how I do it, but since the formula used to compute the standard errors is supposed to be different if I specify `scale` and `rscales`, I would still like to understand why it doesn't seem to affect the standard errors that are computed by `survey`.

P. S. bis: Another thing I don't understand is that, even though the Census Bureau says it has used Fay's method and recommend to use a SAS procedure that will result in a Fay coefficient of `0.5`, there doesn't seem to be any Fay coefficient in the formula for the standard error given in the guide it published. This means that, if I were to write my own code to compute standard errors using that formula, the result would presumably be different than when I use `survey` with a `rho` of `0.5` or the SAS procedure recommended by the Census Bureau to compute standard errors, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svrepdesign` doesn't need `scale` or `rscales` arguments for Fay replicate weights, because it can work them out by itself.  That's the point of having known `type`s of weights.  I should probably add a warning for when you specify them anyway.

There doesn't need to be a Fay coefficient in the formula explicitly. When the weights were constructed, the sampling weights were multiplied by `2-rho` or `rho` to get replicate weights. That's all been done.  Now all you need is to know how to scale the squared residuals.  The Census Bureau formula (p6 of your link) has a multiplier of 4/160. That 4 is `1/(1-rho)^2` -- Anthony Damico's code has the reverse conversion, working out `rho=0.5` from the `4`.

Straightforward BRR would have a multiplier of 1/160 rather than 4/160.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question, and also explains why Anthony Damico wrote ```rho``` that way, which is another thing I was wondering about.